# java runtime import performance

Tags: java

For a project in java (java8 javafx +) I need to import a jar at runtime.
Since I am very interested in the running performance, I wanted to know if importing a jar at runtime can affect performance when using classes in that jar.

Eventually, what would be the best way to dynamically import a jar, always from a point of view to maximize running performance?

Comment: Define 'import a JAR at runtime'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mean you want to include a jar in the runtime classpath of whatever application you are trying to launch. Well your decision to include that jar should be in the first place dictated by the use of classes within that jar. If your code needs those classes you have no option other than to include them in the classpath. Regarding performance of class-loading, usually the JVM loads the classes when if first references them. (Quoting from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html)) when a class is loaded, all classes it references are loaded too. This class loading is repeated until all classes needed are loaded. This may not be all classes actually needed in the application. Also this means that unreferenced classes are not loaded until the time they are referenced.